# How to find a group with generators and relations fulfilling several properties?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I would like to ask the following question:

Let $G:= \langle x,y \mid \text{some relations} \rangle$.

> Is it possible to find a group $G$ as above fulfilling the following criteria simultaneously?

- The order $o(x)$ of the element $x$ is finite: $o(x) < \infty$
- $o(y) < \infty$
- $ N:= \langle x^2 \rangle \unlhd G$
- $ |G|=\infty$
- $ |G/N| < \infty$

When I tried to find such a group $G$, I always ended up with a finite group $G$, but I would like to have $|G|=\infty$.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: The condition $|G/N| \leq \infty$ will always hold. Did you mean something stricter or is this superfluous?

Comment: What exactly did you try? You might be closer than you think. Don't be shy.

Comment: Yes, I mean $|G/N| < \infty$...thank you very much...sorry...I fixed it.

Comment: Your assumptions imply that both $N$ and $G/N$ are finite, so $G$ is also finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lvert x\rvert$ is finite and $N=\langle g= x^2\rangle\unlhd G$ is cyclic, we have

$$g^{\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{2}}=(x^2)^{\frac{\lvert x\rvert}{2}}=x^{\lvert x\rvert}=e,$$

so that $\lvert N\rvert$ is finite. But now

$$\begin{align}
\lvert G\rvert&=[G:N]\lvert N\rvert\\
&=\lvert G/N\rvert\lvert N\rvert\\
&<\infty,
\end{align}$$

a contradiction.

Comment: I've changed my answer accordingly, @BernhardBoehmler.

Comment: @BernhardBoehmler As a general rule, you should avoid editing questions that have been correctly answered. It causes confusion.

Comment: I somehow forgot that $|N|<\infty$...that's embarassing...thanks for the answer! @DerekHolt : Ok, sorry, I will avoid that in the future.